# Extend vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, extend

I have a simple doubt, I want to extend in Matlab a vector:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 n];
```

In the following way:

```
b = [1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 ... n];
```

This means, make a new vector with the double size of the previous one, but the new added values must be the mean of the previous and the next number.

Any idea of a loop to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution

```
b(1:2:2*numel(a)-1)=a
b(2:2:end) = a(1:end-1)+diff(a)/2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use linear interpolation (`interp1`) to solve this problem. Using the `a` vector, we can interpolate values at and between each of the elements.

```
a = [1 2 3 4 17];

b = interp1(a, linspace(1, numel(a), numel(a) * 2 - 1), 'linear');
%   1   1.5   2   2.5   3   3.5   4   10.5   17
```

**Explanation**

What this does is assumes that you have a function `f(x)` where `x = [1 2 3 4 5]` and `f(x) = a`. What you ultimately want is the value of `f(x)` where `x = [1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5]` (i.e. the values and the values *in-between* values. If we use the `'linear'` option, then the in-between values will be replaced with the average of it's neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

without any assumption on order

```
a = [1 2 5 9 17];
d=[diff(a),0]
a2=[a;a+d/2]
b=a2(1:end-1)
```